# When space is removed in a string of input text everything on right should be erased

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an input box which basically deals with hashtags.
Ex: #abc #abcd #abcde

If user decides to delete space in between any of those words, everything in the right should be erased.

Ex: "#abc#abcd #abcde" should not happen in the input field. 
instead the input field should automatically update to "#abc"

Any idea?

Sorry I thought code might not help. Anyway.

```
$("#post_search").keyup(function () {

  $("#post_top_searches").show();
  var ht = $('#post_search_input').val();
  $("#search_display").empty();

  var inputArr = ht.split(' ');
  var arrLen = (Object.keys(inputArr).length);

  var newCount = (ht.match(/\s/g) || []).length;

  if (newCount < currentWhitespaceCount) {

    var str = $('#post_search_input').val()
    var newstr = "#";

    if (newCount === 0) {

      if (((str.match(new RegExp("#", "g")) || []).length) > 1) {

        for (var i = 1, len = str.length; i <= len; i++) {
          if (str[i] === "#") {
            break;
          }

          (newstr = newstr + str[i]);
        }

      } else {
        if (((str.match(new RegExp("#", "g")) || []).length) === 1) {
          newstr = $('#post_search_input').val();
        }
      }
    } else if (newCount > 1) {
      var strArr = str.split(' ');
      for (var i = 1, len = strArr.length; i <= len; i++) {
        strArrLetter = strArr.split();
        for (var j = 1, leng = strArrLetter.length; j <= leng; j++) {
          // pass
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 1, len = str.length; i <= len; i++) {
        if (str[i] === " ") {
          break;
        }

        newstr = newstr + str[i];
      }
    }

    if ($.inArray("#", inputArr) < 0) {
      newstr = $('#post_search_input').val();
    } else {
      for (var i = 1, len = str.length; i <= len; i++) {
        if (str[i] === "#") {
          break;
        }

        newstr = newstr + str[i];
      }
    }
  }

  $('#post_search_input').val(newstr);
  currentWhitespaceCount = newCount;
});
```

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness of your screen? It's a little hard to see the code you've *already tried*...

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you.  Troubleshoot - perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I have some ideas. But show me your's first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code instead:

```js
$("#post_search").on ('input', function () {
    var index = $(this).val().search(/\S#/);
    if (index !== -1) $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, index+1)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id= "post_search" value = "#abc #def #ghi">
```

1. Use of the `input` event is more accurate than `keyup`. The first will also trigger when you change the input via mouse and/or context menu operations (for instance).
2. The regular expression in `search` will find any non-space followed by a hash. If found, the hash and the characters following it are removed.

As hashes should normally only consists of letters, digits and/or underscores, you may want to use `\w` instead of `\S` (which also matches punctuation). Up to you....

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to split the hashtags, using

```
var splitting = str.split('#');
```

`The splitting[0]` is the first hashtag, If You want to You can also insert the hash sign to the beginning you can use:

```
var hash = '#';
var hashtagWord = hash+str;
```

This is called concat. I think the JavaScript course will show You more tricks :)

Comment: I have used concat in the above code. So.
Is there a way to know which space has been removed?